# The usage of "with" and "as“ in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

Can the preposition ***with*** be used in this way with ***as***?

> Under the guidance of our leaders, we participated in the show both physically and virtually, ***with*** online mode ***as*** the main mode and physical mode ***as*** the auxiliary mode.

The context is that the company has just attended a show in-person and virtually.

Comment: It makes sense. What do you think may be wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***With online mode as the main mode*** can be re-written as ***with X as Y*** and yes, it is a commonly used phrase which means:

> ***X being Y*** OR ***while X is Y*** OR ***having X as Y***.

In your sentence this prepositional phrase is an circumstantial adjunct of accompaniment:

> ***Accompaniment*** is a type of *circumstantial adjunct* which represents the meanings and corresponds to the interrogatives *with
> whom?*, and *who/what else?*, *but not who/what?*. It is something
> which is often found with something else.It is expressed by
> *prepositional phrase with preposition such as **with**, **without**, **besides**, **instead of***. ([source](https://media.neliti.com/media/publications/217651-circumstantial-adjuncts-used-in-the-tale.pdf))

About ***as***, CAGEL says:

> The main ***preposition taking a predicative complement*** is ***as***: this is the prepositional analogue of the verb ***be***. The whole *as* phrase may function as complement or adjunct in the larger construction containing it. (p. 636)

As an independent clause *with online mode as the main mode* would be

> "Online mode" ***is*** the main mode.

Comment: Are you happy that _With online mode as the main mode_ pairs the null (it can't possibly be the zero) article with the definite article? '[W]ith X as Y' neatly sidesteps this issue.

Comment: You are right, I didn't even consider that. However, it seemed to me that "online mode" was used as the _name_ of a command, so it didn't strike me as incorrect at the time."With the online mode" would be more correct, arguably, but it somehow sounds natural to me without "the".

Comment: It's reminiscent of the unforgettable line by Kryten on _Red Dwarf_: "Adopt smug mode!"